# Interleave cells from two column ranges

Tags: google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet with words in columns A and B:

```
TxtA1-TxtA2  
TxtB1-TxtB2  
TxtC1-TxtC2
```

How can I merge it into one column looking like this?

```
TxtA1
TxtA2
TxtB1
TxtB2
TxtC1
TxtC2
```

Comment: Please edit the title of your question to be more descriptive of your problem.

Answer (score 1):

*I am assuming that you need a one-off solution to manipulate the data in one spreadsheet, not a repeatable solution that doesn't need any manual copy/pasting.   Please ignore the following if that'd not true.*

Insert two helper columns (they can be temporary if you like), one on the left of the first column, the other on the right of the second column - like this:

H1 - Txt1 - Txt2 - H2

In the first row, set the left helper column value to 1, and the right helper column value to 2.
Then in the other rows, set the values as the one above +2, so they would be like

1 - TxtA1-TxtA2 - 2

3 - TxtB1-TxtB2 - 4

5 - TxtC1-TxtC2 - 6

If you use formulas to set these values, then once the column is made, use Copy / Paste-special Values   to replace the formulae with values.

Then copy the values from the 3rd column to under the 2nd column
Then copy the values from the 4th column to under the 1st column

The select the first and second columns, and sort them by the first column value.

And delete the first column if it's no longer required.

Answer (score 1):

Based on your example, stack B under A and sort.

However a more generalised case might be where all the text content (say in A2:B4) is more variable, for which:

```
=if(ISEVEN(row()),indirect("B"&row()/2),indirect("A"&row()/2+0.5))
```

may suit, if placed in Row3 and copied down to suit.